# Hive : Find row. with. max diff. in two columns obtained from left join

Tags: sql, hive

Table a

```
id   marks
3     23
4     37
5     56
```

Table b

```
id  marks
1    35
2    68
3.   55   
5.   97
```

I want some thing like

`select id , max(a.marks. - b.marks) from a left join b on a.id = b. id`

The output should be

```
  id marks
   5   41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id, (a.marks. - b.marks) as diff
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b. id
order by diff desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned 'table_a left join table_b', it looks you intend to consider all IDs exist in table 'table_a'. we also need to replace 'NULL' with ZERO appropriately before calculating difference in-case there are no matching records exist in table 'table_b'.

Solution# 1 -

```
select a.id, abs(a.marks - coalesce(b.marks,0)) as diff 
from table_a a left join table_b b on a.id = b.id 
order by diff desc limit 1; —- took 36.624 seconds
```

Solution# 2 -

```
Select id, max(diff) 
From (select a.id, abs(a.marks - coalesce(b.marks,0)) as diff 
From table_a a left join table_b b on a.id = b.id) t 
group by id order by 2 limit 1; -- took 46.682 seconds
```